# Is it possible to override a function in JS, while preserving its original lexical scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to slightly modify the code of some function, exposed to me by a third party module. I was thinking of copying the function and modifying it, but the problem is that it relies on other functions and variables that exist in its **lexical scope**. I do not have a problem with the infamous "this" binding, but with the scope itself.

For example, this is the third party library:

```
var someGlobalVar;

function someInnerFunction(){
    //Does something...
}

function functionIWantToAlter(){
    //I want to copy the implementation of this function, and alter parts of it,
    // but i need to preserve its lexical scope.
    const x=5;
    const y=10;

    console.log(x+y);


    someInnerFunction(someGlobalVar)//The function calls some inner function, and uses an inner variable
}

module.exports = functionIWantToAlter;
```

Then, in my code, i want to literally copy this function, but to preserve its lexical scope:

```
const functionIWantToAlter = require('third-party-module');
//Maybe here it's somehow possible to "bind" my override function, to the lexical
//scope of "functionIWantToAlter"?

function override(){
    //Do here something different, than the original function does

    const x=1;
    const y=2;

    console.log(y*x);

    someInnerFunction(someGlobalVar)//Some of the implementation is the same,
    // but my code doesn't have access to the original lexical scope.
}
```

Is there a way this could be done?

Edit: The library i need to "patch" is node-fetch. This is the function:
https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/master/src/index.js

In the npm_module itself the code comes in one big JS file, but i don't think it makes any difference. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: This is not vanilla JS. Please tag the question with any frameworks you are using.

Comment: Per e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472529/accessing-variables-trapped-by-closure you can't access the variables in the closure from outside.

Comment: @WaisKamal I don't see any framework usage here.

Comment: The `module` object is not defined in ordinary JS.

Comment: `module.exports` is pretty standard `node.js`

Comment: @DaneBrouwer that's true. Also, it doesn't really alter anything whether it's `module.exports` or `export` or the older module pattern the result would be the same.

Comment: Need to patch it *to do what*? The point of node-fetch is to be consistent with the browser's fetch, if that's not a goal for you you could look at alternatives that provide for e.g. interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrap that idea. Fork the library and make your edits.

Alternatively you can npm “patch” the library.

Comment: By "npm patching" you mean creating my own copy of the library? If so, is it even legal?

Comment: @i.brod depends on the license of the library. This one is [under MIT license](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/#license), so you have complete freedom to do what you want with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a reference to the original scope you could do

```
 with(originalScope) {
  function fake() {
    //...
  }
 }
```

but as you don't have any way to access the original scope, this is impossible. Also this is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: "*Also this is generally a terrible idea.*" you should probably start with this.

Comment: I've added a reference to the library i need to patch, maybe you can take a look?

Comment: @i.brod why don't you just copy the file and change it to your needs?

Comment: @Jonas yes i can do that of course, i just wanted to see if there's a way around such a solution